# Pedestrians as Opposed to Riders of Vehicles

Tags: classical-latin, word-comparison, word-choice

If I want to use a term to describe someone who walks on foot rather than riding in a vehicle, which should I choose? I noticed that *pedester* could refer to any people who walk rather than riding a horse, and the opposite is *equester*, but are there any words that directly mean a person outside of a vehicle? Or does *pedester* apply to both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pedester* applies to anyone on foot : surely, that already means someone outside a vehicle who is proceeding (or even standing still) on foot? If you really needed to make the distinction of 'not riding in a vehicle', you might make up a nonce-word, e.g. *extravehicularius*. This would be easily understood. You could even extend this principle to define the vehicle which they aren't in : *extracarrucaria*, *extracarpentaria*, and so on (here feminine, because these refer to carriages used by women).